# If statements returning wrong data

Tags: python, json, if-statement, urllib2

I have some code similar to this: It goes though a list and queries an API to check if it returns a JSON object:

```
for one in many:   
    print "Checking "+one
    url = "http://an.api/"+one
    contents = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    print len(contents.read()) > 10
    if len(contents.read()) > 10:
        print "online"
    else:
        print "offline"
```

If JSON is returned, the user is online, if not he is offline. Running the script returns something similar to this:

```
Checking a
True
offline
Checking b
True
offline
Checking c
False
offline
```

It says "True", but why does it print "offline"?

Comment: of coarse it's the if statement that is broken as implied by your title ... not the fact that read is an iterator that is consumed as you use it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save off the read, if you are going to perform multiple operations on the output

```
for one in many:   
    print "Checking "+one
    url = "http://an.api/"+one
    contents = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    myData = contents.read()
    print len(myData) > 10
    if len(myData) > 10:
        print "online"
    else:
        print "offline"
```

Answer (score 2):

You **already read** the data from the URL, you cannot read it again. The second `.read()` call returns an empty string.

Store the read data in a variable first:

```
contents = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = contents.read()
print len(data) > 10
if len(data) > 10:
    print "online"
else:
    print "offline"
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @user3884909: Note that you can accept only *one* of the two answers posted; you cannot mark both as accepted. Glad we both were of help, however!

Comment: That's your choice, whomever helped you the most.